# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE using Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

i am begginer in Liquibase

i need to add DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE and DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE in SQL Formatted Liquibase Script not in .xml, .JSON, .YAML formats

is there any way we can use those statements

Below is the code i am using but getting invalid SQL statement

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset pratap:2
DROP TABLE cat.testdbms;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Test Line1' );
```

Any one can help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that liquibase runs SQL using a JDBC connection, and can only run basic SQL. I think that DBMS_OUTPUT is a procedure in a package. This syntax might work if run using SQL*Plus, but not when run through a JDBC statement. It might be possible to do this if you used the `call` statement:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset pratap:2
DROP TABLE cat.testdbms;
call (DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Test Line1' ));
```

or something like that.

Comment: Hi Steve i had tried it, command ran successfully but i didn't see any printing line Test Line1 in output

Comment: All I can think is that the output is maybe going somewhere unexpected. In the environment you are describing, it may be that the output just doesn't get sent anywhere. Liquibase probably isn't capturing remote output from the server.

What is the underlying problem are you trying to solve?